# How to add variable to chart with 2 ranges vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am tring to make that my chart will take data from 2 ranges that made the my chart, the ranges are for example: E48:G59 and A48:G59.

I switch the rows numbers to variables because I need to add to the chart every time another row so that is relevant part of the code:

```
Let CopyrangeCH1a = "E" & G & ":" & "G" & I
Let CopyrangeCH1b = "A" & G & ":" & "A" & I

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(CopyrangeCH1b, CopyrangeCH1a)
```

I and G are the variables for the rows.

The problem is that when I excute it my chart take in the range of the variable CopyrangeCH1a B48:G59 insted of E48:G59.

Althogh that the code is right and the variables show E48:G59...
(it take the first column after the column that in the secound range)

When I do just 1 range of them in the range with the variable it perfect

Why it do not work o.k with 2 ranges and I can fix it?

Comment: The problem you are having is that the Range(x,y) function creates a Range object where the beginning cell is x and the end cell is y.  You can't have a disjoint range in this way.  I'm not really in the mood right now to figure out the whole thing for you, but I'm guessing you are trying to use these ranges as the series the chart is based on.  I'd use the whole range, "A48:G59" and then set the series in VBA as desired.  If you have a hard time figuring out how to get the series right, record a macro while creating the desired chart and then modify that code.